# Android Eclipse Debug self terminated by no reason

Tags: eclipse, debugging, terminate

I start debuging my app. 
I have first breakpoint and then debugging terminate app and disconnect from it. 
I have no errors in log.

Have You any ideas?

Comment: Come on, that isn't enough, show some code, just anything. Maybe there's a reason for what it did, maybe it hit an error in the code.

Comment: There have no errors in code. Without debug the app is started well.

Answer (score 0):

Solve problem by my self. I remove all breakpoints and set new one. May be will helpful to any one.